# SQL Lite blank row id even after deleting the row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite DB file lets say a.db. And I have 100 rows in table a. When I give

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

it gives me the first 100 results. Now if I delete the first 2 rows from the table and run the

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

it gives me only 98 rows. And when I give the query

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE rowid = 1
```

it gives me an empty row. The database doesn't seem to rearrange the rowid.

Please help.. Is there any way to force the SQLite to rearrange the row ids ?

Comment: what does it mean "empty row"?

Comment: Why did you tag your question as "mysql"?

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, `rowid` is just an int column with [autoincremented](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) values. The only thing you're guaranteed is that each rowid will be unique to that table -- nothing more. You aren't guaranteed that rowids will be sequential, and you aren't even guaranteed that every number will be used! For example, if an INSERT fails, the rowid used in that failed insert will probably be skipped and never used again (if the `autoincrement` keyword is explicitly used -- otherwise, if a row is deleted, its rowid is free to be reused by any newly inserted data.)

If you want rowids to be sequential and autoupdated, you'll have to create your own version of the rowid column and keep it updated with triggers.

Comment: Thanks but we need to run the vacuum to auto fix empty rows.. It is much easier than maintaing out own row_id.

Comment: @Jeba I'm afraid that is your only option. You cannot change the behavior of `rowid` in SQLite. That is, unless you're willing to take the SQLite source code and modify it to add that feature.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. We need to run the Vacuum query after every delete. This will rearrange all the rowindex and remove the dead rows.

http://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html